# How to send a multipart/mixed HTTP POST request through Runscope?

Tags: request, multipartform-data, runscope

I want to send a HTTP POST request with Content-Type: `Multipart/mixed` using [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com).

Any help/guidance would be great.

Comment: what did you try to do?

Comment: I try to test api call for upload photo and upload audio. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to send data through us, each with varying support for multi-part form data.

#### Dashboard

When making requests through the dashboard, there is currently no way to add files or other multi-part data to a request. This is something we plan to support in the future, but we don't have a specific timline for implementing it yet.

#### From your code, via a Runscope URL

When you make a request from code that includes multipart data, it will be relayed through the [Runscope URL](https://www.runscope.com/docs/debugging) in tact. The dashboard will display the file meta data that it relayed, but the files are not stored or displayed and retries will not re-send the file data again.

We're happy to help answer any questions in more detail by emailing us at [help@runscope.com](http://mailto%3ahelp@runscope.com) any time.